# Spring Boot, authorization_code, IdentityServer4 code_verifier

Tags: spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, identityserver4, spring-oauth2

I have integrated IdentityServer4 in spring Boot project.

I want to know how to add code_verifier to call "/connect/token" of IdentityServer?

I receive code in the redirecturl as follows,

**First Redirect:**
https://idsrv4test.com/connect/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=client_id&scope=id_number%20openid%20email%20roles%20profile&state=SDGHMnvw0UJZyylFr752jBAWS2ahGIwBiavF0YsRtoI%3D&redirect_uri=https://127.0.0.1:9443/signin-oidc&code_challenge_method=S256&nonce=_8fJthx0jlqX_2tJKSkwvs_r4RfxIjU4NokGGpSZIF0&code_challenge=<this_encrypted_text>

**Second Redirect**
https://127.0.0.1:9443/signin-oidc?code=returned_code&scope=id_number%20openid%20email%20roles%20profile&state=9KxStmaCkre_-cCqofOSfRO0eWahh-3e19upwYH1rJ8%3D&session_state=Sm-Zq8GcrX43Rc1Ve5elO7ua90aIyXTkJB6lT4tQRhY.ImGYr6V2186LxSMZdLcngg

I construct a resttemplate in my project to call "/connect/token"  as per

POST /connect/token
CONTENT-TYPE application/x-www-form-urlencoded

```
client_id=client_id&
client_secret=secret&
grant_type=authorization_code&
code=returned_code&
redirect_uri=https://127.0.0.1:9443/signin-oidc
code_verifier=<this_encrypted_text>
```

In the requestBody I set code_verifier=<this_encrypted_text>
But I get "invalid_grant". It means as per the spec docs https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7636#page-10
code_verifier == code_challenge.  is flase

For your reference SecurityConfig class is as such

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class ConfigSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {


        PortMapperImpl portMapper = new PortMapperImpl();
        portMapper.setPortMappings(Collections.singletonMap("9443","9443"));
        PortResolverImpl portResolver = new PortResolverImpl();
        portResolver.setPortMapper(portMapper);
        LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint entryPoint = new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint(
                "/login");
        entryPoint.setPortMapper(portMapper);
        entryPoint.setPortResolver(portResolver);
        http.exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(entryPoint)
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/login","/css/*", "/images/*","/signin-oidc","/test")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .oauth2Login()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .and()
                .logout().logoutUrl("/logout")
                .logoutSuccessHandler(oidcLogoutSuccessHandler());


    }

    @Autowired
    private ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository;

    private LogoutSuccessHandler oidcLogoutSuccessHandler() {

        OidcClientInitiatedLogoutSuccessHandler oidcLogoutSuccessHandler =
                new OidcClientInitiatedLogoutSuccessHandler(
                        this.clientRegistrationRepository);

        oidcLogoutSuccessHandler.setPostLogoutRedirectUri(
                URI.create("http://localhost:9443"));

        return oidcLogoutSuccessHandler;
    }
}
```

And my application.yml is as follows,

```
server:
  port: 9443
  ssl:
    key-store: classpath:asif1.jks
    key-store-password: xxxxx
    key-store-type: pkcs12
    key-store-alias: server
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          idsrv4:
            client-name: client_name_test
            client-id: client_id_test
            client-secret: Marines
            client-authentication-method: none
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
            redirect-uri: "https://127.0.0.1:9443/signin-oidc"

            scope: "id_number,openid,email,roles,profile"


        provider:
          idsrv4:
            authorization-uri: https://idsrv4test.com/connect/authorize
            issuer-uri: https://idsrv4test.com
            token-uri: https://idsrv4test.com/connect/token
            user-info-uri: https://idsrv4test.com/connect/userinfo
            user-name-attribute: sub
            jwk-set-uri: https://idsrv4test.com/.well-known/openid-configuration/jwks
```

Any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally resolved this issue. But still not satisfied with the methodology. Yet, it works gracefully. What I expected from OAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver that the request to get the jwt token gets created internally and I should be unaware of the random string generated as code_challenge(to implement PKCE).

I still request to share if somebody has a working example of authenticating and getting token by just providing required confs without me implementing and overriding OAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver.
So, here i go

To implement OAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver please follow https://developer.okta.com/blog/2020/01/23/pkce-oauth2-spring-boot

then in method addPkceParameters

```
     String codeVerifier = this.secureKeyGenerator.generateKey();
    attributes.put(PkceParameterNames.CODE_VERIFIER, codeVerifier);
```

codeVerifier is the string which we need to send alongwith the request for /connect/token

Now, its all up to you how you get this randomly generated string in your controller to send the request.

I have hard coded it ;-)  for  time being. But this I know does not fulfill the purpose of PKCE.

Also, in your class extending WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter , configure(HttpSecurity http) method must contain "/oauth2/authorization" as base url

somethg like this

```
http.exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(entryPoint)
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/login","/css/*", "/static/**", "/images/*","/test","/signin-oidc","/logoutSession")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .oauth2Login()
                .authorizationEndpoint()
                .authorizationRequestResolver(new CustomAuthorizationRequestResolver(
                        clientRegistrationRepository, "/oauth2/authorization"
                ))
                .and()
                .loginPage("/login").and().logout().logoutUrl("/logout")
                .logoutSuccessHandler(oidcLogoutSuccessHandler());
```